# GUI not updating the image on every click because new image of graph take time in generating every new image, so GUI show the previous image

Tags: java, image, swing, graph, swingworker

i  am having problem in displaying the current on the GUI, i am using Swing Worker which is not working according to my requirements. kindly someone help me to update image on every click while image generation take time because image is generated through graph viz. i am struck in my project ...`enter code here`

```
private static void show1(){
            SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker1= new SwingWorker<Void,Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                gp.GraphPanel();// here in graph panel image is not updated         
                    return null;
            }
            protected void done() {
            }
        };      
        worker1.execute();      
            }
    // show1 is called inside action listener 
        public static JScrollPane GraphPanel() 
        {             // some code here
                   ImageIcon imgIcon=new ImageIcon(FILE_NAME.filename+".png");
            label.setIcon( imgIcon);
            pane2.add(label);
                    JScrollPane grphPane= new JScrollPane(pane2);
                    return grphPane;

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqua's answer is the correct means by which you should use `SwingWorker`, but, you're doing nothing with the resulting the instance `JScrollPane` you're creating in the `GraphPane` method

This method creates a new instance of GraphPane...

```
public static JScrollPane GraphPanel() 
{             // some code here
    ImageIcon imgIcon=new ImageIcon(FILE_NAME.filename+".png");
    label.setIcon( imgIcon);
    pane2.add(label);
    JScrollPane grphPane= new JScrollPane(pane2);
    return grphPane;
}
```

But calling it like...

```
gp.GraphPanel();
```

Does nothing with it, you should be adding the result of this method to your UI...

Based on your code example, `label` seems to be an instance variable, if it's already on the screen, you should simply set its icon property and let the UI update it self

```
public void updateGraph() 
{             // some code here
    ImageIcon imgIcon=new ImageIcon(FILE_NAME.filename+".png");
    label.setIcon( imgIcon);
}
```

Also, avoid `static` where possible, it's a good indication that your design needs work

Answer (score 1):

You should access *Swing* components only from *Event Dispatch Thread*. You on the other hand attempt to build and access `JScrollPane` from `doInBackground`. SwingWorker's `doInBackground` is executed on auxiliary worker thread. This is where the background task should happen. If the image preparation takes time, you can execute this action in `doInBackground`. Then, override `done()` method where you can add the resulting image to UI. `done()` is executed on `Event Dispatch Thread`. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.

Here is a simple example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Image, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Image doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("some path"));
        //TODO process the image
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            Image image = get();
            //TODO use the image
            //ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```